# How do I read decimal data from the AS400 DB2database?

Tags: delphi, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I used Delphi ADODB to connect to the AS400 DB2 database, but when I reading decimal type data ,it lost decimal precision.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ3em.png)

Its true value is 736657878664.160. The SQL is a simple "select data form testtable".

```
Cnn := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
Cnn.LoginPrompt := False;
Cnn.CommandTimeout := CCommandTimeout;
Cnn.ConnectionString := lpDB^.CnnString;QryCom := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
try
  QryCom.ParamCheck := False;
  QryCom.Connection := Cnn;
  QryCom.SQL.Text   := sSql;
  QryCom.CommandTimeout := CCommandTimeout;
  QryCom.Open;
  S := 'C:\AS400SQLTest.txt';
  QryCom.SaveToFile(S, pfADTG);
  S := 'C:\AS400SQLTest.xml';
  QryCom.SaveToFile(S, pfXML);
  TextToFile('C:\As400SQL.txt', 'True');
  QryCom.Close;
finally
  QryCom.Free
end;
```

The loss occurs after "QryCom.open". When I change SQL to "select Char(data) as a form testtable", and read by "QryCom.FieldByName('a').AsString", it is true. 
Is there anyone who can help me

Comment: What is the DataType of the column in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Delphi defaults Numeric(15,#) numbers to ftFloat, but that does not have enough precision to hold the entire number. Here is a blog post that suggests remapping that default to ftFMTBCD. [Devart Blog](https://blog.devart.com/data-type-mapping-in-delphi-data-access-components.html)

Comment: Reading normal DB2 database data of type decimal is fine, but reading a DB2 database of AS400 results in a loss of precision after the decimal point.After many attempts, I use python solved the problem.